# How to download pdf from blob url either outside webview application (e.g. redircting to Chrome browser) or inside the webview android app?

Tags: android, webview

I am learning to build Android application so I started with creating a web app.

But stucked at the problem.

I have already searched for it but no success. I've already have seen some similar questions but that didn't worked for me.
Everything in my web view app works fine.
It can download other files. But just stucked on downloading blob url pdf file downloading.

Here is my code.

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        
        checkConnection();
                    
        
//      Enabling the downloading of files.
        
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {       

                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                            long contentLength) {
                                                
                                                
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(userAgent);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookies);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading File....");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype));
                    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                            
                    

                }
            });     
            



        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
                {
                        view.loadUrl(String.valueOf(request.getUrl()));
                    
                    return true;
                    
                }
            });
```

I have to add some more other features but after solving this issue.
So please help me with this with simplest way.

**Thank you!**

Comment: What is a blob url? And you let the DownloadManager do the download which is ok. The DownloadManager does not care about the type of file. Pdf or anything else is the same. So where lies the problem? What does not happen? How do you know the file is not downloaded?

Comment: As you already know what a blob url is if not _(Blob URLs can only be generated internally by the browser. URL.createObjectURL() will create a special reference to the Blob or File object which later can be released using URL.revokeObjectURL(). These URLs can only be used locally in the single instance of the browser and in the same session (ie. the life of the page/document).)_

Comment: I have no idea what this is about. You could give an example of use. And from where, from which http(s) server should the download be done? And that blob . Where does it reside? And you did not answer all my questions. Any reason not to do so? How does such a blob url look like?

Comment: This is what when i try to download the file. `AndroidRuntime  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:https://example.com/b044c373-0bb9-4a63-a4b6-d10727976176`

Comment: I know the file is not downloaded because its not in download folder or anywhere in the storage. The download manager is able to download the files like .pdf, .mp3, .jpg if its already generated (ready) on the server. But in this blob case the data for the file is already present on the page we just have to first convert it to base64 then do some javascript thing. But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: AndroidRuntime  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:https://example.com/b044c373-0bb9-4a63-a4b6-d10727976176

Comment: For some reason I can't share the original URL. Sorry.

Comment: Place it between ticks to make all grey. We dont see http or https now and i think its in it. That link spoils it.